# How to remove title bars in Gnome?

Tags: themes, gnome-shell, window, titlebar

I'd like to remove the title bars in Gnome Shell. Running Ubuntu 18.04 with Gnome and the Adwaita theme.

Is there a file I can edit to remove the title bars off the windows? It's really wasted space. I use shortcut keys to close windows, press alt if I need menus, and move things around with alt + mouse click. I'd love to give that screen real estate back to my browser or terminal.

Extensions don't seem to work. I want to know where in the code of the theme these title bars are so I can either delete them or change them. I remember doing this in the past, but don't want to hack away at files indiscriminately like last time.